# Proving $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{a}$ by use of limit definition

Tags: epsilon-delta

$$  \frac{-|x-a|}{a|x|} < \varepsilon  $$

Then i did was assume  $\delta = a/2$ and got the values where $x \in (a/2,3a/2)$. Idk what to do next and im sorry idk how to format.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because the body of your question is incomprehensible. Start from the beginning and use real sentences please.

Comment: @Bob Don't worry about the negs. It takes a while to get the hang of this place. It's not like the usual online forums. Start by writing down exactly what you need to prove according to the definition of a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are on the right track.  Let's assume that $x>0$ and $a>0$.

We first take $a/2<x<3a/2$, which means that $|x-a|<a/2$.

Next, let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac1x-\frac1a\right|&=\frac{|x-a|}{ax}\\\\
&<\frac{|x-a|}{a(a/2)}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-a|<\min\left(a/2,\frac12 a^2\epsilon\right)$.

> The case for $x<0$, $a<0$ follows an analogous line and is left as an exercise.

Comment: im confused how did u get a/2 for x?

Comment: Bob, if we fix the point $a$, then certainly $\delta$ has to less than $a$ else there would be values of $x$ such that $x$ is within $\delta$ from $a$, but $x<0$.   So, we choose to confine the problem (arbitrarily) by choosing the larges $\delta $ can be to ensure $x>0$ for all $|x-a|<\delta$.  So, and number less than $a$ suffices.  Here, $a/2$ was selected.